# Magento 2 Check Component Dependency fail

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I'm having problems upgrading Magento 2 (Current version 2.0.7). When I tried to upgrade I got the following error:

```
Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .
```

My cron job is setup as follows:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

I have searched for hours upon hours for a solution but can't find a solution. Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you try this? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html

Comment: Try to run these 3 cron manually from terminal and  then check.

Comment: Tried running the cron jobs and they don't seem to through any errors and yes I've looked at troubleshooting but still no help

Comment: Are you updating it via Composer? Try composer update

Comment: @Mark Do you still have this issue? When are you getting this error (what command exactly). Do you have custom modules installed?

Answer (score 0):

- Look for `.htaccess` and change (*twice*):

  php_value memory_limit 2048M

  php_value max_execution_time 0
- Look for `.user.ini` and change:

  memory_limit = 2048M

  max_execution_time = 0
- Look for `nginx.conf.sample` and change (*twice*):

  fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=2048M \n max_execution_time=0";

This value of `memory_limit` must be set to `2048M` as well in your own `php.ini` used for the crontab tasks.

---

I guess this is not completely related, but for my localhost MAMP, this is my current commands for CRON used:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/bin/magento cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/update/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```